# logarithm function in a polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, lambert-w

I faced the following polynomial equation which has a logarithm function inside of it:
$\\ x^2 + \ln(x) - a = 0 $.
I could manage to use approximation in small $x$, ($0<x \ll 1$) to solve this equation by the conventional methods ($\ln(1+x) \approx x$):
$$
x = x^\prime + 1 \\
(x^\prime -1)^2 + x^\prime + a =0
$$
I wonder if I can solve this equation analytically without using such approximations.
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you required to find the exact value of $x$?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to avoid numerical methods for this one (if it's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x>0$
$$x^2+\log(x)=a\implies x^2+\frac12 \log(x^2)=a$$ Let $x^2=t$, muliply by $2$ and exponentiate
$$t+\frac12 \log(t)= a\implies 2t +\log(t)=2a\implies t e^{2t}=e^{2a}\implies 2t e^{2t}=2e^{2a}$$
Let $2t=u$ to make the nice
$$ue^u=2e^{2a}\implies u=W\left(2 e^{2 a}\right)$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Now, back to $t$ and $x$

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} W\left(2 e^{2 a}\right)}$$ which is defined $\forall a$.